# Accessing Static Resources in springBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to Access images which are placed under static folder (**resources/static/images**) in `SPRINGBOOT`.

[image]

now I want to get image `PATH`, But getting null pointer exception.

```
 parameters.put(
            "imageLink",
            getClass().getResource("images/header.png").toString());
```

Comment: but in the above question i clearly mention that i have placed my images in static folder that's the problem. if i did like that then my question is duplicate. i don't want to know how to place image in jasper report. please read my question care fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the image directly in the report:

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="60"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["static/images/header.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

---

Or pass it into the report by parameter as an `Image` instance:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/static/images/header.png"));
parameters.put("header", image);
```

And use it in the report like this:

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="60"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{header}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Where `header` parameter class in report is as `Object`.

---

Or pass it as an `URL` instance:

```
URL headerUrl = getClass().getResource("/static/images/header.png");
parameters.put("header", headerUrl);
```

Where `header` parameter class in report is as `URL`.

```
<parameter name="header" class="java.net.URL" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Then the `imageExpression` in `image` element is the same as in previous example.